# How to expand into initializer list with fold expressions?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I would like to insert as many zeros into a vector as there are arguments to a variadic templated function (i.e. *number of arguments* zeros into a vector). I am trying to use fold expressions to achieve this and it works when using `(vec.push_back(zeroHelper(args)), ...);`.

What I do not understand: Why does it not work when I try to initialize the vector directly by "unfolding" into an initializer list like follows:
`std::vector<int> vec = { (zeroHelper(args), ...) };`?

Full source code:

```
template <typename T>
T zeroHelper (T a) { return T{0}; }

template<typename ...Args>
void printer(Args&&... args) {
    std::vector<int> vec; // = { (zeroHelper(args), ...) };
    (vec.push_back(zeroHelper(args)), ...);
    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    printer(1, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

[And here's the source on OnlineGDB.](https://onlinegdb.com/HklHv7jv8)

Expected output:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   0

Output with the initializer list approach:

> 0

Why?

Comment: why didn't you forward your elements to zero helper instead of copying l values from printer

Comment: Following the advice of @asmmo, I got this: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7ccbf679a86d7b6). (Parameter packs are not (yet) my strength. Hence, I became curious to puzzle this out.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in

```
std::vector<int> vec = { (zeroHelper(args), ...) };
```

the parentheses return only one element, the last one;  the comma operator discard the precedings.

You should write

```
std::vector<int> vec = { zeroHelper(args) ... };
```

to maintains all elements.

In

```
(vec.push_back(zeroHelper(args)), ...);
```

the parentheses activate the folding, the comma discards all elements except the last one but the `push_back()` operation is applied to `vec` for every `args...` elements.

Observe also that, using the discarding propriety of the comma operator, you don't need `zeroHelper()` at all

You can write

```
std::vector<int> vec { ((void)args, 0)... };
```

or

```
(vec.push_back(((void)args, 0)), ...);
```

Comment: Hmm, `{ zeroHelper(args), ... }` does not work, it yields the error message "expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token". However, `{ zeroHelper(args) ... }` (without the comma) seems to work.

Comment: @j00hi - yes, sorry: the comma is implicit in the `...` expansion.

Comment: @j00hi - answer improved with a couple of examples

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that discarding behaviour of the comma operator. I actually prefer the version without `zeroHelper`. Thanks a lot!